# Select Columns In Select Query Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

```
Declare @tempvar as Varchar(10)
    Set @tempvar='true'

    select dbo.InformationTable.Name,dbo.InformationTable.Address,dbo.InformationTable.FavoriteDish
    from dbo.InformationTable
```

I want to show `dbo.InformationTable.FavoriteDish` column only when `@tempvar` is set to `true`,else it will not include in select statement?How can i achieve this.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately **there is no efficient way** to conditionally exclude a column from a `SELECT` query.

You can either do it this way:

```
DECLARE @tempvar AS VARCHAR(10)
SET @tempvar='true'

IF @tempvar = 'true'
BEGIN
    SELECT
        dbo.InformationTable.Name,
        dbo.InformationTable.Address,
        dbo.InformationTable.FavoriteDish
    FROM
        dbo.InformationTable
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT
        dbo.InformationTable.Name,
        dbo.InformationTable.Address
    FROM
        dbo.InformationTable
END
```

Or, if you don't mind the column descending anyway as part of the resultset (with `NULL` values), like this:

```
SELECT
    dbo.InformationTable.Name,
    dbo.InformationTable.Address,
    CASE
        WHEN @tempvar = 'true' THEN
            dbo.InformationTable.FavoriteDish
        ELSE NULL
    END FavoriteDish
FROM
    dbo.InformationTable
```

You also could build your query dynamically in a `VARCHAR` variable and pass it to the `EXEC` method:

```
DECLARE @myquery VARCHAR(1000)

/*
Build your query here on your own conditions
*/

EXEC(@myquery)
```

**I strongly advise against the last one**, though, because [it comes with multiple tradeoffs](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .Is there is no cool way instead of replicate the code?

Comment: The *cool* way might be using the third option I gave you, but as I said this is something I don't recommend. In T-SQL you must favor the *efficient* way over the *cool* way. Always.

Comment: IMHO you should ask yourself why you want to exclude the column at server level instead of having the client make the right query.